# Writing recursive template haskell functions

Tags: haskell, recursion, template-haskell

Is it possible to transform a recursive TH function into an equivalent form which will compile? The following definition doesn't work, because in order to compile `fact` you must first compile `fact`.

```
fact :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
fact n = [|
    case $n of 
      1 -> 1
      _ -> $n * $(fact [| $n - 1 |]) |]
```

This simple example is easily solved (`fact n = [| product [ 1.. $n] |]`) but in the general case, if it is not possible to rewrite a given function as a loop, can a recursive TH function be defined? Is there even a single example for which this doable?

To clarify for future readers: this question is specifically about writing *recursive* TH functions - not about 'how do I splice the factorial function'.

The answer to my question turned out to be remarkably simple:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Monad.Fix (fix)
import Language.Haskell.TH

fact = [| \f x -> $([| 
     case x of 
       1 -> 1 
       _ -> f $([| x - 1 |]) * x  |]) |]

factorial = [| fix $fact |]
```

`fact` can be compiled because it is no longer recursive, and `[| fix $fact |]` is compiled at a *later* time, so no more infinite recursive definitions.

This version of `fact` looks slightly different than the original, but you can write the new `fact` exactly as the old one and transform it later:

```
fact' recurse n = [|
        case $n of 
          1 -> 1
          _ -> $n * $(recurse [| $n - 1 |]) |]

fact = [| \x -> $((\f -> [| \x -> $(fact (\x -> [| $f $x |]) [| x |]) |]) [| x |]) |]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your code is not that it is recursive, but that it doesn't terminate. The `n` argument to `fact` just keeps getting bigger and bigger because `[| $n - 1 ]|` is an expression tree representing the operation `(-)` applied to `n` and `1`.

Any non-terminating splice will hang the compiler in just the same way, for example the following behaves just like your `fact` when spliced:

```
broken :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
broken n = return $ LitE (IntegerL (fromIntegral (length [1..])))
```

A recursive function where the recursion is guaranteed to bottom out is guaranteed to terminate and works fine for appropriate inputs:

```
fact1 :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
fact1 n = do
    nBody <- n
    case nBody of
      LitE (IntegerL 1) -> [|1|]
      LitE (IntegerL nInt) | nInt > 1 ->
          let nMinusOne = return $ LitE (IntegerL (nInt-1))
          in [| $n * $(fact1 nMinusOne) |]
```

but of course it fails if the input isn't an appropriate integer literal.

You can also shift the recursion to runtime, so that instead of the recursive call being with an ever-bigger expression tree, it's with the runtime evaluated and shrinking `Int`:

```
fact2 :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
fact2 n =
   [|
    let factImpl n =
         case n of
          1 -> 1
          _ -> n * factImpl (n-1)
    in factImpl $n
   |]
```

Of course in this code we're not doing any analysis of the structure of `n`. But we can put it together with `fact1` to get a version that is compile-time executed in some cases and defers others to runtime:

```
fact3 :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
fact3 n = do
    nBody <- n
    case nBody of
      LitE (IntegerL 1) -> [|1|]
      LitE (IntegerL nInt) ->
          let nMinusOne = return $ LitE (IntegerL (nInt-1))
          in [| $n * $(fact3 nMinusOne) |]
      _ -> [|
            let factImpl n =
                  case n of
                    1 -> 1
                    _ -> n * factImpl (n-1)
            in factImpl $n
           |]
```

Ultimately in your real code, you will need to apply some combination of these techniques - make sure that your compile-time recursion terminates and defer any remaining cases to runtime evaluation somehow.

Comment: You are just splicing the entire `fact` function. If this were the goal, I could write my code without any use of TH at all. With this approach, I can't perform any manipulations using TH within the function, because the inner `n` cannot escape its scope.

Comment: The point applies in general though - you need to transform your code so that the recursion is at runtime, using tricks like this. If your recursion won't bottom out at compile-time, your code can't work.

Comment: I added an example of doing recursion that does terminate on the TH expression, to illustrate that your problem is non-termination, not recursion itself.

Comment: The second function you added only works on literals - sort of redundant, if my function can't even be applied to variables, providing an even weaker form of the first function.

Comment: It's just to illustrate that terminating recursion is ok. As I said, your problem is that your recursion doesn't terminate, nothing else.

Comment: I reorganised my post to present the options more clearly and added a 'hybrid' version.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, even though it doesn't answer my question, because my question was quite poorly worded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by using the following:

```
fact :: Int -> ExpQ
fact 0 = [| 1 |]
fact n = [| $(lift n) * $(fact $ n - 1) |]
```

`lift` is a function inside `Language.Haskell.TH.Lift` which converts a basic haskell values into template haskell values (eg `Int` to `ExpQ`).

Note that you don't need the case code to be generated, as you know the number at compile time. The above macro will expand to a series of multiplications. Eg `$(fact 4)` will expand to `4*3*2*1`.

Note that in this case, you can do much better though. A template haskell expression is run at compile time, so a template haskell `fact` function can just return the literal value it represents. Eg `$(fact 4)` can return `24` (instead of `4*3*2*1`). This can be done with the following code:

```
fact2 :: Int -> ExpQ
fact2 n = lift (product [1..n])
```

Comment: What gave the impression that the input would be known at compile time? This is not the case at all, which is why my example function takes a `Q Exp` arguement and not `Int`.

Comment: Well if the input isn't known at compile time, what value are you giving for the `n` parameter when you are using the macro? If you want to just write a template haskell function that expands to the definition of a factorial function, you want the macro to have the type `Q Exp`, not `Q Exp -> Q Exp`.

Comment: @user2407038 : Template Haskell is a compile-time pass.  If the input isn't known at compile time, you'll need to use the GHC Api or similar to dynamically compile code at run-time.  This sort of thing is possible now (http://johnlato.blogspot.com/2012/10/runtime-meta-programming-in-haskell.html), but will be better soon (http://gmainland.blogspot.com/2013/05/type-safe-runtime-code-generation-with.html)

Comment: My function of type `Q Exp -> Q Exp` can be converted very easily to just `Q Exp` (`\f -> [| \x -> $(f [| x |]) |]`); they are isomorphic. I am indeed trying to splice a function and not a value. @JohnL Typed TH would certainly be extremely useful! But I don't believe it is really relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @user2407038: I'm a bit confused about your last comment, as `Q Exp` and `Q Exp -> Q Exp` do not appear isomorphic to me (and neither does your example code). Can you give a code example as to how you would use the `fact` macro? Maybe that will clear up some confusion.

Comment: @user2407038: I agree typed TH isn't helpful for the problem at hand.  My point is, if you want to have a TH splice depend on a runtime value, you'll need to jump through some hoops.

Comment: The function I included in my last comment (namely `\f -> [| \x -> $(f [| x |]) |]`) converts `Q Exp -> Q Exp` to `Q Exp` by bringing the parameter into the splice. @JohnL Yes, it looks like I will, but it feels as if there should be a simple solution.